# Can I add numerical building health to the corner HUD?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I already know how to add a number to the target ID box so I can point at teammates and buildings to find out exactly how much health they have. But I can't find a way to do it for the Engineer's HUD so I can read the health of buildings without having to point at them. I can find the file that controls the relevant panels but can't find how to access the health value that the regular bar display uses (i.e. tried parameters such as `%health%` but it doesn't work).

Comment: Interesting - how do you add the number to find teammates health?

Comment: You edit `SpectatorGUIHealth.res` in `resource/ui` to include some `CExLabel`s attached to `%Health%`, which provides health as a number. I'm looking for how to do the same with with the top-left building display because `%Health%` doesn't work for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible, as no hooks for this are currently available.